# Uploadify Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

EDIT:

It seems the issue is to do uploadify not having a session, therefore it could not access the page I was sending it to.

So make sure you point it to a page with no admin login security ;)

This was due to an issue with the url that uploadify was accessing. As it has no session it couldn't retrieve anything.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation for the "on" functions. Looks like you've got the wrong arguments for onAllComplete. If you're only uploading single files then just use the onComplete function. That's what I ended up doing. The video example I watched had the arguments interchanged as well so maybe they changed the signature in a recent version which would explain part of your trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The flash file is the object doing the communicating, so you need to submit the session ID with the scriptData option:

'scriptData': { 'session': '<?php echo session_id();?>'}

See: http://www.uploadify.com/faqs/how-do-i-send-the-session-id-to-the-back-end-script/
for more info.